# Hide columns of a particular row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, hide

I want to hide a certain columns of a particular row..i tried this but it doesn't seem to work.any ideas? This is my code:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].visible=false;
```

Comment: You could handle the `CellFormatting` event and remove the content so the cell seems empty

Comment: What event are you putting this code in ? Make sure it's in the RowDataBound event

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of hiding only some cells of particular row. If you do not want to hide whole column then you have to create custom cell that would look like `DataGridView` background and that is quite easy but you would need to handle click events, key events etc for that cell and that is quite troublesome.

My suggestion is to change your approach.